# computed margin has a subpixel deviation from declared value

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a annular ring based infographic meter written in css
its made of semi circular rings. Its made of 4 semi-circular rings created using a square div with colored border on two adjacent sides and border-radius 50%;

I have declared the border radius of a semi-circular ring as 15px, but the computed style is 14.4px in Chrome(my version - 50). I tried to reproduce in jsbin http://jsbin.com/muxaloruro/edit?html,css,output. In jsbin the output is perfect but in my website layout its 14.4px.

I have inspected the computed styles of the element the declared style is 15px but the computed style is 14.4px.

[image]

can any inherited style influence margins or the box-model of a div.

Comment: Are you zoomed in? Try setting zoom to 100%

Answer (score 1):

`border-width` is not affected by any inherited style.

My guess is that your page is zoomed in. At 125% zoom level, I get the same computed width as shown in your screenshot.

Comment: so why does browser behave differently in zoomed in states

Comment: It has something to do with Google Chome scaling of elements.